# How to run a Tor exit node securely on a vps

Tags: tor

I want to run a TOR exit node on a vps, what security measures do I have to put in place on the vps? I know it will be a huge target for hackers and the three letter word agencies in the USA so I need to tighten up every possible security hole possible.

Can I use tor ramdisk as my vps OS? Also can I run a openVPN VPN from the same vps?

Answer (score 3):

This is a really borad question. In essence you have said: "I am going to install a service on my Linux VPS that will make it a target to hackers. How do I secure my Linux server?"

All of the standard security measures should be taken. Most distro's have specific guides on hardening the OS as well. Of course follow the four basic rules:

1. Run all services and programs with lowest privileges.
2. Disable or delete any services not needed on the machine.
3. Ensure the system is up to date.
4. Employ a firewall and host based IPS.

With a little more info on specific threats you are worried about, or distro and software version I may be able to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is covered well on other questions on this site.  See especially [Hardening Linux Server](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/993/971) and [VPS security best practice](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/10818/971).

Others that may be of interest include [Secure Linux Desktop](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4136/971), [Available Resources for Securing RHEL 6](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12561/971), [What methods are available for securing SSH?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39/971).